# Can't get transaction data older than 7 months from customer account data api with developer account

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, transactions, custom-exceptions, customer-account-data-api

I am using a free development account, rails 4.0, ruby v2, heroku toolbelt, redis-server, and postgres 9

I have a rails app that had been loading transactions from Aug. 2013 to Feb. 2014 this past Feb..

In March the app loaded back to Sept., saw that we had hard-coded 7 months, so I switched to load 9 months. The transactions will not load farther back than Sept., both for the cc bank test accounts and a personal bank of america account. It will load a shorter time period(3 months) but calls further back than 7 months only load 7 months.

the main calls I'm making

```
def services
    IntuitIdsAggcat::Client::Services
end

def fetch_transactions
    @transactions = services.get_account_transactions(
         account.user.intuit_id, account.intuit_id, 9.months.ago
    )
end
```

Is there a limit on how far back you can look at transactions with the free development account?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got from Intuit APP team - it sucks :)

We only capture 180 days prior to the add day and that is dependent on the FI. Some FIs we can only get 90 days at most.